# No repeat values in a column using vlookup

Tags: duplicates, vlookup, countif, logistics

Totally new to this.

Sheet1 ColumnB is a list of product numbers. Column C:U are their location numbers in a warehouse.

In Sheet2 I am building a color coded map of the warehouse racking so that a co-worker can visually look at the location number and using Sheet2 they can find the list of product numbers in that location. Associate products will be grouped in adjacent locations under a particular color, so that if they don't have the product number for what they want it should still be easily found. Co-workers know the thing they are looking for. Not the product number.

Quantity tracking is not necessary.

I am using vlookup to find values in Sheet1 to fill a column in Sheet2 with the below formula:

=IF($G8="","",iferror(vlookup($G8,'Copy of RACKING FAMILIES'!$B3:$U550,2,0),"-"))

It is working, but is delivering the same value in every cell of my column. I need it to list down the column, each individual value it finds in the table_array that is in the same row as the lookup_value.

The lookup_value will have several different values in it's row in the table_array on Sheet1. (some locations contain more than 1 product)

I am trying to avoid individually adjusting the formula in each cell of Sheet2. How do I make it so that the column on Sheet2 shows no repeated values?

I have tried to use IF/COUNTIF but may be applying it wrong. However I don't think it is designed for my needs.